# admin-ajax.php responding with 0

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, javascript

I have been trying to port some previously functional ajax over to a WordPress plugin that I am helping to develop.

On the front end my javascript looks like

```
// this is inside a succesfully called JS function
jQuery.ajax({
   action: 'mbp-deleteFrame',
   url: mbp_Ajax.ajaxurl,
   type:"POST",
   data:{'deleteFrame':id},
   success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
      }
 });
```

In my main plugin file I also have

```
<?php
   function mbp_admin_scriptInsert(){
    wp_register_script('mbp_admin_scripts',
         plugins_url('/js/mbp_admin_scripts.js', __FILE__), array('jquery')  );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mbp_admin_scripts');
    wp_localize_script('mbp_admin_scripts', 'mbp_Ajax', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php' ),

           )
     );

}

add_action('wp_ajax_mbp-deleteFrame','mbp_deleteFrame_handle' );
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mbp-deleteFrame','mbp_deleteFrame_handle' );
```

The other function that my add_action commands  refer to is

```
function mbp_deleteFrame_handle(){

    echo ' This is a response!';

die();
```

I am just learning how to manage WP interactions with AJAX, but so far it has proved to be a fruitless process.

Right now,  my understanding is that i need to pass the url of admin-ajax.php to the JS with `wp_localize_script()`. From what I can see I have done this, and it has been given to the AJAX call with the line `url: mbp_Ajax.ajaxurl`. Then, I have `action: mbp-deleteFrame`, as I understand it, this line should trigger either of the two `add_action()` functions that I have on the backend, and call "mbp_deleteFrame_handle()". From there, I would think that I would get my echo in a response, but right now, I am only getting a 0, both in my Console, and in Chrome's response tab.

Could anyone give this a second look and tell me where I am falling short?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `action` has to be an HTTP argument, try that :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: mbp_Ajax.ajaxurl,
    type:"POST",
    data:{
        deleteFrame: id
        action: 'mbp-deleteFrame',
    },
    success: function(resp){
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```